# Can I take hard drive from one PC to another to copy files?

Tags: windows-7, hard-drive, desktop-computer

My computer won't start, sometimes start. I have very important files on it. Can I take hard drive from that computer plug it to another and then copy files? I know that I cannot boot system from that hard drive on other computer, but will I be able to copy those files from that hard drive?

Comment: Most of the times yes,  you can. If encrypted it's way harder, with the user password, and impossible without it.

Answer (score 1):

It really depends on what part of your computer is broken. If your hard drive is broken no point to mounting it to another computer.

In my opinion your best option is to create a bootable USB stick for Ubuntu, so your OS will not be depend on your current storage. Use Ubuntu live and move your data to another storage.
here is a link that walk you through: https://tutorials.ubuntu.com/tutorial/tutorial-create-a-usb-stick-on-windows#0

There may be some problems:

- If your computer was running on Windows 10 and you didn't shut it down properly, you have to mount your partitions manually with "mount" command. Because Windows 10 take a snapshot and saves the current state information before you shut it down to boot faster when you start it next time(called Hybrid shutdown or Fast boot). So if you can start your computer once and shut it down without fast boot you will be fine. Here some explanation if you're interested: https://askubuntu.com/questions/145902/unable-to-mount-windows-ntfs-filesystem-due-to-hibernation
- If you can't start your computer at all, then take out your hard drive and use a dongle(SATA or whatever you need) and connect it to another computer and copy your data and you will be fine.